# What is the best way to communicate between PC and USB device

Tags: c#, usb, communication, usbserial, usb-flash-drive

Scenario is, I have an USB device with flash card for storage in it. I am going to write a PC app using `c#` to communicate/exchange data with this device. Something similar to various SYNC programs

Two options that come to my mind are:

1. Expose flash card as mass storage device and simply copy the required data
2. Use CDC-Data

Now, if I use first option, is there any way I can run some `autorun.bat` file upon connection of this device to check if the required PC app is installed or not and if not installed, guide the user to download from specific website?

If I use the second option, then I think user has to explicitly download required PC app and only then he/she will be able to exchange the data (such as `iTune`)

Kindly suggest if there is any other way to achieve the same?

Best Regards

Bharat Mane

Answer (score 2):

Various versions of Windows support an autorun feature, but I think it has been disabled to some extent in later versions because it is a security risk.

I would make it a composite device where one function is mass storage and another function is general (uses WinUSB/libusb).  Then put a little downloader called setup.exe on the SD card and tell users to run it to install the drivers and software.

Comment: Yes it's been disabled in latest versions of Windows OS and on XP it's been disabled through patch upgrades.